# supplying 240V power to a hardwired heater -OR- a 240V receptacle

Tags: electrical

So I currently have a hard-wired 240V heater in my garage:
[image]
Though I don't use the heater often, I'd like to have the option to use it so my thought was I could have a 3-way switch that would switch on power to one or the other, never both.  Is this possible?

The 240V heater is on a 30amp breaker and is rated for 30amps so I'm pretty sure the wiring from heater to panel is to code.

In the photo you can see there is a switch to optionally cut off power to the heater and I thought that this could be replaced with a 3-way switch that could either be off, power hard-wired heater, or power a 240V EVSE receptacle that would have to be branched off of the box.  For the receptacle, I was thinking since my charger can be optioned with a NEMA 6-30 plug, that a NEMA 6-30 receptacle would be correct since there's only 3 wires from panel to heater (to my understanding a NEMA 14-30 would require a fourth wire to be run from panel to box).

Comment: Those heaters are heavy loads I would want something more than a 30 amp rated snap switch, could it be done yes I would want a switch rated for a load disconnect if you use a standard switch you will find out why fairly quickly.

Comment: ok... so you're saying that the existing snap switch may or may not be sufficient.  what is the name for the switch that i'm asking about... is it a 3-way switch?  what amperage rating should i be looking for?

Comment: The question is very unclear...are you trying to alternate between the heater and an EV charger? Ignoring that possibility, switching such a heavy load with a simple switch is dangerous as @EdBeal pointed out. The best best would be a heavy duty contactor  operated by a low voltage (ie: 24v) transformer and switch or thermostat.

Comment: @Jeff -- does this switch need to fit in the existing box?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest option would be to change the heater input to cord&plug, and put the receptacle required on the wall, and plug in one, or the other.

For a fair amount of money as switches go, you can get a 30A rated DPDT (douple pole double throw) center-off switch that does what you ask. The one I could find was in the "very beefy standard switch" look and may be similar to what you have (Presumably DPST) if it's properly rated for the load. The one I found was rated for motor load disconnect use.

You may also be able to find that function in a "gray box on the wall with a big handle" format, but I struck out (I found plenty of disconnect switches, which are single-throw and don't do what you need.)

If you want to completely overcomplicate it (but it might actually cost less) there is the "use a contactor relay" method mentioned in comments. It strikes me as overcomplicated, and it might also be code-dubious as you'd be assembling a system from recognized parts (we hope - beware of Amazon, etc. for this sort of product,) rather than using a directly listed product.

Comment: There are DPDT switches in the "Gray box on the wall" format (called "double-throw safety switches") -- GE's TC35321 is the cheapest I can find

Comment: I figured there were, just had a hard time finding an example when looking for one.

Answer (score 1):

### Negative, Ghost Rider. EVSE's need a *dedicated branch circuit*

A branch circuit is defined as the stuff *past* the last breaker.

So extend the 30A circuit down to a subpanel.  The subpanel has two 30A breakers.  **You must pinkie-swear not to turn both on at once**.  A physical interlock is not required. The breaker, which is rated SWD, entirely replaces the stupidly inaccessible switch.

So, I would run EMT metal conduit (a new craft to learn, *but* it handles ground for you) and 1/2" pipe will suffice. Easy to work with once you get the  hang of it. And before you get the hang of it, it is trivial to undo/redo, it comes apart like an Erector Set.  **EMT conduit also satisfies the "protected from physical damage" requirements** for wiring in garages.  Now you don't have to bust out drywall.

A suitable location for a panel is somewhere it's not likely to be cluttered up with junk in the 30"x36" *working space* in front of the panel.

Inside the panel, install an accessory ground bar, and remove the green screw on the neutral bar, to un-bond it. That will protect you in case some numbnuts tries to put a 120V circuit there (which it can't support).

Cost would be around $25 for the subpanel, $10 each for 2 breakers, and pencil in $30 for the requisite EMT conduit,  plus $30? the NEMA 6-30 recep.

### Wiring it

With EMT, you simply use THHN wires -- all will be #10. They are available in a variety of colors, and many hardware stores sell it by-the-foot.  You need at least 7" coming into a junction box.

Once the EMT conduit is finished, I'd run four #10 wires - red black orange orange.  The switch goes away and is replaced with a 4x4 domed cover - you need the cubic inches in that box for 4 splices.  Make sure the utility-side and heater-side ground wires are bonded to the box metal. Then the EMT carries ground down to the subpanel.

Red and black go from supply in the former switch box, to the main lugs of the subpanel.  The subpanel gets two 30A 2-pole breakers in it.

Orange and orange go from the 2 hot wires going into the heater, to a 30A breaker in this subpanel.  With American 240V with 2 hot wires, nobody cares which wire is which.

From the NEMA 6-30 recep for your EVSE, run a wiring method of your choice (again I like EMT because it carries ground and satisfies physical-damage resistance requirements) to the subpanel, where it lands on the other 30A breaker.

Comment: This is unsafe and wrong advice.
You're advising him to run a 60-amp sub panel on a 30-amp breaker which is illegal (pinky swears won't pass inspection)
The heater might require a dedicated branch circuit but the EVSE doesn't (maybe local jurisdiction) but residential EVSE is limited to Level 1 and Level 2 which come standard with plugs (like you recommended them install) which by nature cannot dictate a dedicate/individual branch as an outlet can't be a "one utilization equipment" as defined in the NEC.

Comment: so is the better solution to convert the heater from hard wired to plug and install a receptacle?

Comment: or are you saying that by installing a receptacle the circuit is no longer “dedicated” so doing a heater hard wire to plug conversion might not be allowed?

Comment: @Jason -- no, the EVSE requires a *dedicated branch circuit* for the *outlet* feeding it -- it's right there in the NEC in 625.40.  Also, even if pinky swears don't pass inspection, a breaker interlock certainly will.

Comment: this seems to be getting pretty complex.  I’m starting to think cheapest and simplest would be to replace my heater with one that has a 6-30P and replace the box with a 6-30R.  My EVSE can be optioned with a 6-30P so with two 6-30P and one 6-30R I have the ability to use one or the other but not both.

Comment: Should be able to simply change the input on the heater, rather than get a whole new heater.

Comment: @Jeff check your instructions and see whether it's authorized for a cord-and-plug.  Heaters usually aren't.  However you can always hardwire the heater line to an **inlet**, and then use a short jumper cable between outlet and inlet, specifically allowed in NEC 400.7(A)(11).

Comment: @Jason you are wrong and you shouldn't say things like that without specific Code citations (not least to force you to, um, read it).  First, there's nothing wrong with a 200a subpanel on a 30A feed.  Oversubscribing panels (30A feed supplying subpanel breakers summing to >30A) is certainly allowed; look at your own main panel; *unless the user expects to run >30A of load at once* and the user does not.  And I'll grant that EV regulation is fast-changing, but in NEC 2014 it definitely required a dedicated circuit (unless it was plug-in).

Comment: @Jeff **IF** the heater is listed for cord-and-plug connection, **then** there's no need to have precisely one 30A socket.  30A circuits are specifically allowed to have as many sockets as you please (however all must be 30A).  Back in 2018 or so, this came up several times, and we searched exhaustively for anything that would prohibit this, and to our surprise we found nothing. (We did find explicit prohibitions for 40-50A, so we were sure we hadn't missed something).

Comment: @Harper : from the manual and product page there’s no mention of optional plug configuration.

Comment: Man, that pinkie-swearing is the hardest part....